# Adobe Premiere won't update audios

Tags: premiere, audio, audition

I'm having a problem where if I edit an audio clip that is used in my Premiere project with Audition, the change isn't heard in Premiere. Here are the steps that I'm going through:

1. I have an audio-track used in my project.
2. I change it in Adobe Audition.
3. I save it in the same directory with the same name.
4. I delete it from the project's timeline.
5. I delete it from the project's list of imported files.
6. I re-import the new file.
7. I put the file into my project's timeline again.

Needless to say, I re-save the project every two seconds just in case.

My problem: The audio stays the same as it were before the editing. Am I missing something obvious or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try deleting the cache around time in your sequence causing trouble. You can mark an In and Out point, then clear the cache between those to points using "Delete Render Files In to Out" in the Sequence menu.

You don't necessarily have to delete all of the cache (although try that if nothing else works).

These are the steps I would normally take to do what you're doing:

1. Import an audio file in Premiere and place it in a sequence.
2. Right click on the clip in the sequence and choose Edit Clip in Adobe Audition
3. Edit the audio file in adobe
4. Save in adobe
5. The updated audio should appear in Premiere after a few seconds

Premiere sometimes needs to convert your file before it sends it over to Audition, so you might be modifying the wrong file in Audition without realising it if you're doing it all manually instead of letting Premiere manage it.

Comment: It works, thank you!